# How to connect localhost Oracle sql developer database in to Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have Spring Boot java (Gradle) application deployed on Pivotal Cloud Foundry and I have Database connection with local Oracle SQL developer which is 18.2.0.183 version. After deploying the service to Cloud Foundry and creating user provided service in PCF to connect to my local DB, Cloud Foundry doesn't let me connect to my local Oracle Sql Developer DB. It throws this error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

So How can I properly send a Oracle config in user provided service so that it connects.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work for me. Please help ! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500674/pivotal-cloud-foundry-connecting-to-external-oracle-database)

Comment: That SO post should work, the issue is most likely that your Oracle DB is not routable from your app running on Cloud Foundry. Either your local Oracle DB is running on your laptop and not accessible elsewhere, or there is probably a firewall somewhere, possibly even your `cf security-groups`, blocking the connection.